# Visual Studio Skip certain errors while compiling

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

Is there a way to have Visual Studio 2010/2012 skip over certain compiler errors and just keep compiling the rest of the code.

I keep getting this error for DNN and I don't need it.

> 'ControlName' is not a valid value for attribute 'classname'

Comment: If you don't need it, remove it. If a compiler error could be ignored, it wouldn't be an error.

Answer (score 2):

No, a compiler error means that there is something fundamentally wrong with your code, such that the compiler is unable to determine what executable code to generate.  Syntax and semantics errors must be fixed and cannot be skipped to achieve successful compilation.

Warnings, however, can be skipped or suppressed because they indicate a potential mistake or issue, rather than a blocking one.